# Using scanf for structure input

Tags: c

The code attached with this post is part of a bigger program but I am experiencing problems while taking in input for my structured variable 'title' and 'author'.
The program seems to loop over it and move on to the next line. Also, while using [^\n] before 's' in the string specifier, it does the same however I read it is used to take a string as input using scanf. Read a few posts but can't figure out the issue. 
Just starting with C, any help would be appreciated!

```
struct books{
char title[30];
char author[30];
char subject[20];
int quantity;
int book_id;
char *category;
int count;
float price;
};
struct books book;

book.book_id=id;
printf("\n\n\t\tBook Name:\n\t\t");
scanf(" %s",book.title);
printf("\n\n\t\tAuthor:\n\t\t");
scanf(" %[^\n]s",book.author);
printf("\n\n\t\tQuantity:\n\t\t");
scanf("%d",&book.quantity);
printf("\n\n\t\tPrice:\n\t\t");
scanf("%f",&book.price);
```

Comment: It might be the space before %s

Comment: Does your format specifier really contain `[ ^ \ n ]` rather than `[^\n]`?  You don't want the extra spaces there either. The `[^\n]` specifies `\n` specifically rather then any whitespace as a string delimiter.  If you tried that, then that is the code you should have posted. Does it work when the input does not contain spaces or is that a problem too?

Comment: [mcve], please! BTW, the `s` after `[^\n]` is wrong and should be removed. This won't have any effect though but is completely superfluous.

Comment: It is [^\n] and without the spacing it is not working. The extra spaces was a mistake while copying, edited the post @clifford

Comment: @SyedHasan : If you "have read" about something; you should post a link or state what you actually read, because it was either wrong or you misunderstood it.  the `[^\n` is not part of the format specifier, but a delimiter specification.

Answer (score 0):

Use [^\n] before 's' in the string specifier in both the input "book.title" and "book.author".

I executed your code with those modifications. The code is correct.

**You have been taking a space seperated String as the Title of Book.**(like "Mein Kampf" as the Title.)

But you must understand that **you cannot input space seperated words as a single String using Scanf**. So the program loops over it and moves to the next line.

To take such inputs you will have to use *gets* or *fgets* function or use [^\n] before 's' in the string specifier.

Comment: gets(book.title) actually does the same. Loops over the title to the author.

Comment: You *can* accept strings with spaces using scanf.  See the answer now marked as a duplicate.  Whether it is wise to use scanf at all for string inpout is another matter.

Comment: @SyedHasan :  What do you mean by "loops over"? Your code fragment contains no loops.  Do not use `gets()` - even worse that `scanf()`!  The the question marked as duplicate, examples using fgets() and `scanf()` are given.

Comment: Use [^\n] before 's' in the string specifier in both the input "book.title" and "book.author".
I executed your code with those modifications. It runs smoothly.